# Quando usar redux e state no react

Tags: react, redux

Percebi que podemos usar o Redux e o State para trabalhar no react. Quando usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utiliza-se **State** dentro da lógica do seu componente, para armazenar alguma informação não persistente inerente à ele, algo que dependendo dessa informação você vai usar para renderizar algo ou dar fetch numa api. Alguns exemplos comuns do uso de state são:

- Armazenar os dados dos `inputs` em um componente `Formulario` para dar fetch quando o usuário clicar para enviar
- Em um componente `relógio` o state pode ser a hora que o componente vai renderizar na tela, atualizando esse valor a cada segundo ou minuto

Já o **Redux** é uma árvore de estados, que persiste entre os componentes. Em geral no react uma informação é levada de pai para filho na hierarquia através de atribuições na `props` dos componentes, porém as vezes essa estrutura começa a ficar muito complexa e você precisa de em mesmo dado em componentes em níveis bem distintos de hierarquia. O redux possibilita que você acesse um estado "global" entre os componentes que o compõem.

O State e o Redux são coisas bem diferentes, enquanto o state é um conceito básico nativo do react o redux é um pacote de terceiros muito útil no desenvolvimento de apps complexos.

Uma dica que eu dou pra você que está começando com react é aprender os conceitos básicos antes, construir alguns componentes e procurar alguns projetos pra desenvolver, no momento que você começar a ter problemas quanto a passagem de dados de componentes pai para filhos dentro do seu app muito provavelmente é a hora certa de você aprender sobre o redux.